# How to pass src directory to the classpath with maven eclipse plugin

Tags: maven-2, eclipse-plugin, classpath, pom.xml

My project structure is not like "src/main/java". How can I give src directory manually from pom.xml?

PS:I tried  and  tags. resources is applying the include command but,by default act, it also adds an exclude **.*.java also so it is not working. sourceIncludes is doing nothing:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

build

```
<sourceDirectory>../java-path-to-source </sourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes><include>**</include></includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
<sourceDirectory>${basedir}/your-source-directory</sourceDirectory>
```

to the `build` section of your POM.